# How to obtain the inverse of a function?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

I am trying to solve this

$$f(x)= \frac{-5}  {x^2 + 1}$$

The solution is

$f^{-1} = \pm\frac{\sqrt{-x-5}} {\sqrt{x}}$

I have done 
$$x = \frac{-5}  {y^2 + 1}$$
$${(x)(y^2 +1)} = {-5} $$
$${y^2 +1} = {\frac{-5}{x}} $$
$${y^2} = {\frac{-5}{x} - 1} $$
$${y} = \sqrt{\frac{-5}{x} - 1} $$

But I do not get the final answer as yo can see, I need to use the inverse to get the range of the original function,can someone please guide me in how to solve this exercise

Comment: If you simplify, you will see that your answer is actually the same as theirs, except you are missing a $\pm$ sign

Comment: $f$ is not a bijection since it is even. Hence it has no inverse.

Comment: How can I simplify my answer to get the correct?

Comment: This function has to have an inverse, the orignal example has range

Comment: why do you need the inverse to find the range of $f.$ you can find the range of $f$ directly. use the fact that $x^2 + 1 \ge 1$ to get the range of of $[-5, 0).$

Comment: Oh I did not know that until Zubin Mukerjee and you wrote it, can you elaborate more

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mentioned you want to find the range of the original function. To do this, recall that a fraction gets larger in absolute value as the denominator gets smaller. But the function always takes on negative values, so its minimum (if it has one) will occur when the denominator is as small as possible. $x^2+1$ is minimized at $x=0$, which gives the minimum as

$$\frac{-5}{0^2+1}=-5$$

There actually is no maximum value for the function, because the denominator can get arbitrarily large, and the function will get arbitrarily close to $0$ from the negative side, but never actually reach it. So the range, in interval notation, is $$[-5,0)$$

---

As for the inverse you found, it doesn't match the final answer because you forgot to consider the negative root for $y$ in

$$y^2 = \frac{-5}{x}-1$$

The two roots are

$$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-5}{x}-1}$$

This is equivalent to the given answer:

$$y = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-5}{x}-1} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-5}{x}+\frac{-x}{x}} = \pm \sqrt{\frac{-x-5}{x}}$$$$$$

You can use the inverse function to get the same result for the range of the original function, using two ideas: if you're working in real numbers, you can't divide by zero, and you can't take the square root of a negative number.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I understand better with the examples of the inverse function

Comment: do you have another example for the first answer you wrote?

Comment: @Learner Sure, consider the function $$f(x) = \frac{1}{x-\sqrt{x}}$$

What are its domain and range?

Comment: [1, 0)? the min x -sqrt(x) is 0?

Comment: To find the domain, notice that there are two restrictions: the square root can't have a negative in it, and the denominator of the fraction can't be zero. This means that $$x \geq 0 $$ and $$x-\sqrt{x} \neq 0$$

What are the values of $x$ for which $x-\sqrt{x}=0$? Use this to find the *domain* of $f$. Do this and then we can find the range.

Comment: 0, 1 are the values, x > 1  the denominator is not 0,  so the domain is x > 1

Comment: How can I obtain the range if I already have the domain?

Comment: The denominator is $0$ when $x=0$ or $x=1$, but it is nonzero for $0<x<1$ in addition to $x>1$ as you said.

Comment: thanks for the explanation

Comment: sorry to bother you again why the range is y<= 4 in addition to y > 0? I tried to subtitute the values of the domain in the function

Comment: It's actually $y \leq -4$ or $y > 0$, and the reason is that the denominator can reach all negative values in the interval $$[-1/4,0)$$ and can reach all positive numbers in the interval $(0,\infty)$. To see that the minimum of $x-\sqrt{x}$ occurs at $x=\frac{1}{4}$ and is equal to $-\frac{1}{4}$ may require calculus, so perhaps my example isn't the best one for the range of the function, but it is a good exercise for the domain anyway.